# Rstudio and R both freeze when plotting with plot() and ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, freeze, restart

I have a problem since that has to do with plotting in R and Rstudio. I am using a MacBook Pro 14'' with macOS Monterey Version 12.1. The RStudio version is 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353), and the R version is 4.2.2.

I was previously using R 4.2.0 and a previous version of RStudio and still the plots did not show up.

What happens is that as soon as I try to plot anything, the panel freezes and the only way to go forward is to press the red "stop" button of the console. Usually, the only way to go is to restart R because pressing the stop button is not enough. It happens with any plotting function that I am aware of, including ggplot(), hist(), and plot().

I have already tried to restart the laptop, to unload the packages and to update them.

Did anybody encounter a similar issue? It's quite puzzling to me.
Thanks,
Marco

I have already tried to restart the laptop, to unload the packages and to update them.

Comment: Does this only happen when you view plots in the viewer pane, or does this also happen when you export a plot to a file?

Comment: It happens in both cases: I cannot export the plot to a file if I cannot view it on the viewer pane. And most importantly, as long as the "stop" button remains on, I cannot do anything (including exporting the plot to a file).

Comment: Just to confirm: did you try to export via the export buttons in RStudio or did you use graphics devices in the console/`ggsave()`? Because if the console works, it might be an issue with RStudio rather than the setup.

Comment: I tried to use graphics devices in the console, and the console did not work when I tried to run either a plot() or a ggplot(). It also happened in base R (not using Rstudio)...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. my system did not recognise the Arial font. After installing it manually, ggplot worked again.

Thanks!
M